# NHibernate - how to fluently map id based property to be one way from domain model to database

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Inside my app entity is identified by a string key - a baseN representation of its ID like 
`xAdWzC` which  is a BaseN (52) representation of numeric Id.

numeric Id is generated using similar to oracle sequence algorithm, before insertion ( my custom id generator).

How do I map my class that basicly has 2 representations of Id to be saved in db with 2 columns one numeric - primary key and the other - a string key to identify rows in db better? I obviously dont need 2 primary keys and would prefer numeric PK.

A string key is just a property that wraps around numeric key in C# like this

```
public string Key
{
     get { return BaseNFunction(Id); }
}
```

Basicly I want this mapping to be one way to db. When item is loaded from db this column has to be completely ignored.

How would the NHB mapping look like?
Is the question difficult or its just wasn't spotted? I dont think its worth a bounty but please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the generated property readonly (it's `access="readonly"` in XML; look for something similar in fluent)

Read-only in this case means *the property is read from the entity and written to the DB, but not the other way around*

Comment: thanks I guess it should be it. However I am wondering whether it is guaranteed that first it will assign the id to object, and then it will be reading properties , while persisting to db? If id isn't assigned this value is invalid in my case.

Comment: That's a good question. I tested with the HiLo generator, and it works as expected; I think it should be the same with Sequence (I don't have any db supporting sequences available to test)

Answer (score 0):

Make your numeric key the primary key. This will automatically give it a unique constraint and an index. Then make your string key column just a regular column with a unique constraint explicitly. Don't forget to also add an index to the string column if you plan on doing lookups by it.

Comment: yeah the question is how the mapping will look like. Ill edit it maybe it wasn't clear from question.

Comment: Do you use fluent or mapping files? I'll edit my answer to include the appropriate mappings.